# Django Admin: Inline of a filed's field

Tags: django

I have the following model definition:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
   ...

class Children(models.Model):
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Membership(models.Model):
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to preview a person's children inline in the Membership admin view

Comment: There is a edit pen-like button on side by person selector in Mebership admin view, and clicking it can popup the person admin view, so you can add inlines which union a subclass of TabularInline for Children in PersonModelAdmin.

Comment: @Blackdoor, I understand, but I wanted everything to be in the same view

Comment: if so, you need override a method of ModelAdmin.